# Cannot add the msExchArchiveGUID in Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, office365, guid

I cannot add the GUID value for msExchArchiveGUID in powershell. Error reports of "constraint violation" or "A value for the attribute was not in the acceptable range of values" depending on which powershell cmdlet is used. From what I can tell the value that needs to be input needs to be up to 16 characters. Anything more and it errors. For example, the GUID value I need to write is 5C669E441173CF4394995E43EC8ED9ED. When pasted using ADSIEdit the output looks like: 5C 66 9E 44 11 73 CF 43 94 99 5E 43 EC 8E D9 ED. If I add the same value using Powershell it errors. How can I write the value in Powershell to give the same result like adding using ADSIEdit?
E.g 
`Set-aduser -identity "someone" -add @{msExchArchiveGUID="A format the works!
"}`

Comment: Did you try using the Microsoft provided AD cmdlets? Set-AdUser.

Comment: This reports "A value for the attribute was not in the acceptable range of values"

Answer (score 0):

The solution is a bit convoluted (and probably obvious to all but me!) which I will show below.. I'm sure a more concise answer is out there..

I get the GUID value using quest (rather that get-remotemailbox)

```
Get-QADUser -Service domain -Identity someone -IncludeAllProperties|select msExchArchiveGUID

    This presents the archive GUID as 5C669E441173CF4394995E43EC8ED9ED

    So.....
    $oct = "5C669E441173CF4394995E43EC8ED9ED"
    $oct1 = $oct.substring(0,2)
    $oct2 = $oct.substring(2,2)
    $oct3 = $oct.substring(4,2)
    $oct4 = $oct.substring(6,2)
    $oct5 = $oct.substring(8,2)
    $oct6 = $oct.substring(10,2)
    $oct7 = $oct.substring(12,2)
    $oct8 = $oct.substring(14,2)
    $oct9 = $oct.substring(16,4)
    $oct10 = $oct.substring(20,12)

    $strOut = "$oct4" + "$oct3" + "$oct2" + "$oct1" + "-" + "$oct6" + "$oct5" + "-" + "$oct8" + "$oct7" + "-" + "$oct9" + "-" + "$oct10"
```

Output is "449E665C-7311-43CF-9499-5E43EC8ED9ED"

```
    $Id = [GUID]("449e665c-7311-43cf-9499-5e43ec8ed9ed")
    Set-ADUser -Identity $IPGUser -Clear msexcharchiveGUID
    Set-ADUser User -Add @{msexchArchiveGUId=$id}
```